# Vantagens e desvantagens do SQLite

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite

> O SQLite é uma poderosa API para trabalhar com dados estruturados, porém exige do programador muito esforço para usá-la. Segundo Developer (2018), o programador enfrenta o famoso “boilerplate code”, ou seja, o programador deve implementar muitos códigos para atingir determinada funcionalidade. Tomando como referência os principais problemas enfrentados pelo programados com o uso do SQLite. Julgue as afirmativas a seguir em (V) Verdadeiras ou (F) Falsas.
>
> (   ) Não há verificação da linguagem SQL em tempo de compilação. Caso o programador forneça o nome de alguma coluna que não exista, ainda assim o aplicativo não será interrompido quando estiver sendo executado no aplicativo do usuário.
>
> (   ) Se a estrutura do banco de dados é modificada, será necessário atualizar todos os comandos SQL manualmente.
>
> (   ) O programador deve implementar o código responsável por converter a linguagem SQL e os objetos em Java.
>
> Assinale a alternativa que apresenta a sequência CORRETA:
>
> Escolha uma:
>
> a.  V - F - V.
>
> b.  V - V - V.
>
> c.  V - V - F.
>
> d.  F - F - V.
>
> e.  F - V - F.

Estou com dúvidas entre a 1º e 2º alternativa, porém a ultima sei que é verdadeira.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta original é um pouco ruim e ambígua.

Embora o SQLite possua uma API, ele em si não é uma API. *Boilerplate* só é necessário para dar flexibilidade, e é simples o programador criar mecanismo que evite isso de acordo com suas necessidades, e só ele pode fazê-lo porque só ele entende essas necessidades, mas infelizmente hoje a maioria dos programadores não entendem mais o que é desenvolver software, apenas ficam reproduzindo códigos prontos e acham que estão fazendo algo bom, sem entender o que está acontecendo ali.

As afirmações são mal pensadas e escritas por quem não entende exatamente o que está acontecendo. Então cabe interpretação, e, portanto, pode ser que minha resposta não bata com o que a pessoa pensou. Por causa disso as três afirmações são falsas. Mas provavelmente a intenção de quem fez isso era outra, e só ela sabe.

- É claro que se um código SQL tenta acessar uma coluna inexistente dará um erro e isso deve ser tratado pelo seu código. Ele não interromperá a execução, claro, mas nada será realizado, a API não foi feita para causar esse tipo de coisa. Porém não faz sentido falar em compilação aí. A afirmação parte de premissas erradas. Em certo sentido ela é verdadeira, porque não haverá a interrupção, mas não pelos motivos apresentados, então prefiro colocar como falso.
- Não necessariamente precisará atualizar todos os comandos SQL no seu código quando a estrutura do banco de dado é atualizada. É possível e até provável que sim, em alguns ou até boa parte dos casos, mas todos seria um exagero. Por isso prefiro dizer que é falso, afinal se parte é falso, acho que ela acaba sendo falsa.
- Não há conversão de linguagem SQL e objetos. O que há é a inserção de resultados recebidos nos objetos, ou a leitura dos dados do objeto para mandar para o banco de dados. É possível usar alguma biblioteca ou desenvolver algo que faça isto de forma automática, isso é chamado de ORM. Mas não é obrigatório. A afirmação usa uma premissa equivocada, portanto ela é falsa.

Se quiser interpretar o que a pessoa tentou fazer, talvez, e só talvez, as três sejam verdadeiras, mas muita especulação tem que ser feita para isto, tem que entrar na mente da pessoa que escreveu isto. Mas poderia ser qualquer combinação que a pessoa pensou.

As afirmações assim fariam todas serem verdadeiras:

- O código SQL é um texto inserido dentro do código Java, por isso ele não é verificado em tempo de compilação. Se no código estiver um nome de coluna inexistente na tabela o comando SQL não trará um resultado útil e haverá um erro que o código Java deve tratá-lo.
- Se a estrutura do banco de dados é modificada, possivelmente será necessário atualizar alguns dos comandos SQL usados no código Java de forma manual.
- Sem o uso de uma biblioteca extra, a transferência entre os dados dos objetos e do que é mandado ou obtido através da API básica fornecida pelo SQLite é de responsabilidade do programador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A pergunta da faculdade é *um pouco* ruim? Você está extra gentil hoje. :)

Comment: É por essas e outras que dá pra dizer sem medo que diploma de TI, por si só não vale nada. Os poucos que saem formados são os que aprenderam por conta própria (infelizmente no Brasil isso não se aplica só a TI, claro).;

Comment: sim mas apenas respondi te agradecendo , não esta certo.

Comment: @Jeovane E o que você queria então?